# Using a question mark without a question word

Tags: punctuation

Today, I came across this sentence in an article. My question is, how come there is a question mark without a question word?

**"These strategic responses all sound familiar?"**

Comment: In general, punctuation is there to tell one how to pronounce the text when reading.  The question mark implies that the text should be read with the sort of rising intonation at the end that implies a question.  It is extremely common, in English, to pose a question without a "question word", using only intonation to convey the sense that a question is being asked.

Comment: @HotLicks - Is it acceptable in written English as well? I mean, in academic writings.

Comment: To the extent that a question mark is acceptable, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken that's because an interrogative word has been omitted. In this case the sentence with the word would read **"Do these strategic responses all sound familiar?"** but it's still a valid question without it, or at least you can understand the meaning.

Another example would be **"You're going to the shops?"** It would otherwise be written **"Are you going to the shops?"** but the question is still clear.

Source:

My mother is an English teacher

Also [Section 4](http://englishsentences.com/interrogative-sentence/) "Not all interrogative sentences will use question words"